# Is It Safe and Secure To Enable WebDav on Production IIS 7.5 Website?

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, webdav, publishing

We are looking for a way to securely publish new website updates to a production website, hosted on IIS 7.5. We've considered FTP, VPN, and now looking at WebDav since it seems to be the easiest to turn up, configure, and use.

One of our concerns, however, is that it can be used without any strange side effects, such as weird files it writes to the web directory, similar to FrontPage Server Extensions. And our biggest concern is that is opens security vulnerabilities.

Does any have anyone have any experience or advice in this area?

Also, has anyone else solved this problem with a diffenent tool than those I listed (FTP, TPN, WebDav)?

Thank so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) exists for exactly this purpose. You *could* use WebDAV for deployment, but it adds unneeded complexity.